# What is the meaning of 0xdeadcab1 fault address

Tags: android, android-ndk, jvm-crash

I have observed this value in the r3 or x8 register (on ARM) a handful of times when crashing in native code on Android. The crash is always caused by `signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)`. I was wondering if the specific value `0xdeadcab1` offers any additional information (like `0xdeadbaad` indicates a heap corruption) or is it synonymous with `SIGSEGV`/`SEGV_MAPERR`?

Comment: what does `ndk-stack` say?

Comment: It's always (in my experience) a result of attempting to allocate memory - `operator new` or `malloc` in the stack trace. `std::bad_alloc` or LLVM's `__cxa_exception` usually precede the termination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `0xdeadcab1` constant is [hardcoded](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/bfa632c/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/src/terminate.cc#52) in Android's C++ runtime called GAbi++. This runtime, upon termination (i.e. a call to `std::terminate()`), dereferences this address to make it stand out in stack traces. `cab1` is meant to stand for "C++ ABI". The GAbi++ runtime isn't the default on Android, but it is [embedded in STLPort](https://android.magicer.xyz/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html#ga), which was a common STL implementation on Android for a long time (it has been removed in NDK 18 in favour of `libc++`).

I have observed this apparent segfault in out-of-memory situations, where a `std::bad_alloc` is thrown, but if exceptions are disabled, it will fall back on `std::terminate()` (which will dereference this address in order to generate a segfault under GAbi++). I wouldn't rule out other scenarios also causing the same segfault.